# How to get the redirected URL using AFNetworking?

Tags: html, ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I use AFNetworking  get method, the url is something like :

http://www.hi-pda.com/forum/redirect.php?from=notice&goto=findpost&pid=31089630&ptid=1631932

using chrome I can see the true URL is :
[image]

It is in the location .

How can I get the url when using AFNetworking , I tried the following method, it does not work

```
[
    manager GET:threadNotice.URLString
    parameters:nil
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[operation.response allHeaderFields]);
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    }
];
```

The response is

```
2015-05-31 00:11:03.349 HiPDA V2[20006:751020] {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Sat, 30 May 2015 16:10:59 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.6.2";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.10";
}
```

no location field,how can I get that? thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the answer used the following method:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation=[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_URLString]]];
    [requestOperation setRedirectResponseBlock:^NSURLRequest *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *redirectResponse) {
        if (redirectResponse) {
            //this is the redirected url
            NSLog(@"%@",request.URL);
        }
        return request;
    }];
    [requestOperation start];
```

Comment: Simplest answer I found here!